# El disparador BEFORE INSERT solo funciona en un BEFORE UPDATE

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, trigger

Tengo este disparador (*trigger*) llamado `BEFORE UPDATE` en *MySQL*:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` TRIGGER 
`CalcularCamposCalculadosActuacionesU` BEFORE INSERT ON `actuacion` 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    SET NEW.TieneFiltrosValidos = 
        (select case when a.IdActuacion in 
        (select ac.IdActuacion from actuacion ac
         left join MaestraEstado es on es.IdMaestraEstado = ac.IdMaestraEstado
         where (((es.Valor <> "FIN") and (es.Valor <> "REVISA"))
                  or (ac.Incurrido2016 > 0)) and (es.Valor <> "ELIMINADO") 
                ) then "Sí"
                else "No"
         end Valor
     from actuacion a
     where a.IdActuacion = NEW.IdActuacion);`
```

Según unas condiciones, sacadas de una tabla maestra, quiero rellenar el campo de la entidad `actuacion` con un `"Sí"`, si cumple la condición, y de lo contrario un `"No"`.

En el disparador `BEFORE UPDATE`, sí, me actualiza dicho campo, mientras que en el de inserción, no.

No me salta ningún error ni nada, simplemente me deja ese campo a nulo.

Comment: Tal vez no tenga nada que ver con el tipo de trigger, sino con el resultado de la consulta dentro del trigger. En todo caso, es difícil ayudarte a menos que podamos reproducir tu error. Considera compartir un script que sea un [mcve]. Y, de paso, te sugiero usar comillas simples en vez de dobles para las cadenas como `FIN` o `REVISA`. Ese es el estándar SQL.

Comment: @sstan la consulta esta bien, en ambos triggers es la misma y en el del insert no funciona pero en el del update sí. Por eso el post, porque siendo exactamente igual el contenido del trigger debería funcionar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que la consulta dentro del trigger no devuelve ningún registro en el caso de un `INSERT`, por lo que el campo `TieneFiltrosValidos` queda a `null`.  Si simplificamos la consulta, lo que tienes es básicamente:

```
select ...
  from actuacion a
 where a.IdActuacion = NEW.IdActuacion
```

En otras palabras, estás buscando el registro que estás a punto de insertar.  Pero cómo estás dentro de un `BEFORE INSERT` (énfasis en ***BEFORE***), eso quiere decir que el registro aún no existe en la tabla `actuacion`, por lo que la consulta no te devolverá ningún resultado.

Por supuesto, en el caso de un `UPDATE`, lo cosa es diferente, porque el registro ya existe antes del `UPDATE`, y por eso funciona.

Te tocará revisar el diseño de tu consulta.  En realidad, el que estés tratando de consultar la misma tabla a la que estás insertando me parece un poco raro.

Aquí te dejo una versión modificada de tu consulta, que pienso debería ser equivalente a lo que estás haciendo, pero evita que el trigger intente consultar el registro que está a punto de insertar. Con más entendimiento de lo que haces, seguramente se puede mejorar.

```
SET NEW.TieneFiltrosValidos = (
  select case when exists (
    select null
      from (select null) x
      left join MaestraEstado es
        on es.IdMaestraEstado = NEW.IdMaestraEstado
     where ((es.Valor <> 'FIN' and es.Valor <> 'REVISA') or NEW.Incurrido2016 > 0)
       and es.Valor <> 'ELIMINADO')
  then 'Sí' else 'No' end);
```

También, te menciono que posiblemente tienes un defecto con tus condiciones `es.Valor <> ..`. Porque en cada uno de esos casos, parece que es posible que `es.Valor` sea `null`. Si eso llega a ser el caso, toma en cuenta que el verificar un valor `null` con el operador `<>` no evaluará a `true`, como tal vez esperas. Como seguramente sabes, las comparaciones con el valor `null` se deben hacer con `IS NULL` o `IS NOT NULL` para que funcionen correctamente.

Comment: Claro es verdad! gracias ya entiendo porque no me funcionaba,por otro lado tenias razón en lo del es.Valor <> ... por lo que tuve que volver la sentencia "del reves" y buscar los tengan un determinado valor. En un principio puse esa condicion para no tener que andar si el valor es.. y ademas no es nulo y ademas... y evitar tener demasiadas condiciones. Pero eso ya está solucionado, gracias por avisarme!